# vba macro - find first blank column from specific row range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

Most of the solutions I have googled were either about finding the first blank column or first blank row, but I specifically need to find the first blank column in a range of rows.

What I need is to paste something from a workbook to another workbook, but first, I need to find the first blank column in a range of rows from (100:114).

I could post what I have so far, but its far from working.

Comment: Post it so we can see.  This will also show us exactly what you are trying

Comment: You need to find which column is the left-most that has rows 100 to 114 blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my VBA skills are completely rusty, but if you look at Tom Urtis contribution on [How to: Select a Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198177(v=office.14).aspx) Selecting a Data Range of Unknown Starting Location on the Microsoft Developers Network, it has the necessary objects and methods that you should need to workout a solution to what you are looking to do. Below is a reprint of the code from that link:

```
Sub UnknownRange()
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There is no range to be selected.", , "No cells contain any values."
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim FirstRow&, FirstCol&, LastRow&, LastCol&
    Dim myUsedRange As Range
    FirstRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    FirstCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox _
        "There are horizontally merged cells on the sheet" & vbCrLf & _
        "that should be removed in order to locate the range.", 64, "Please unmerge all cells."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
    Set myUsedRange = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    myUsedRange.Select
    MsgBox "The data range on this worksheet is " & myUsedRange.Address(0, 0) & ".", 64, "Range address:"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, I would have tried to work out the code myself, but, I upgraded to Microsoft Office for Mac 2016 this weekend, and well, they shipped without a functional VBA Editor. :-(